# Increase PFFile Parse Upload Size with iOS

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, parse-platform, pffile

I am trying to increase the size of my parse upload size for my PFFile for my PFObject. Here is the snippet of code that explains what I'm doing

```
//Save Essentials
let object = PFObject(className: "posts")
object["username"] = PFUser.current()!.username
...
let videoData = NSData(contentsOfFile: self.videoURL.relativePath)
let videoFile = PFFile(name:"vid.MOV", data:videoData!)
object["vid"] = videoFile
object.saveInBackground()
```

so After I try saving in the background.. it loads.. makes to it 100% then stops and gives me back this error.

```
[Error]: request entity too large (Code: 0, Version: 1.14.2)
```

I've done some searching, but I honestly can't find anything explaining how to fix this.

I am using **Parse With Heroku.**

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ethan, there's a limit for uploads (called **maxUploadSize**). By default, it's 20MB (see https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/src/defaults.js#L28)

You can change it using the ParseServer constructor (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/src/ParseServer.js#L121).

Comment: I am using Heroku though with mLab Mongo DB. Is there way to access this constructor?